# Potential bad assumption in surjectivity proof for coding function?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

Given a coding function between pairs of naturals and naturals:

$$
\begin{gather}
\phi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \\
\phi: m, n \mapsto 2^n(2m + 1) - 1
\end{gather}
$$

The notes attempt to show bijectivity by first showing injectivity and then surjectivity. I have no problem with the injectivity proof. However, I am not understanding the surjectivity proof. It is laid out below:

> For a given natural number $y \in \mathbb{N}$ we show how to construct $n$ and $m$ such that $\phi(n, m) = y$.
>
> This is a relatively straightforward reversal of the function. We begin by noting that we assume $y = 2^n(2m + 1) − 1$ so the number $y + 1$ is of the form $a \times b$ **where $a$ is an even number and $b$ is an odd number.**
>
> - We can find $a$ by viewing $y + 1$ in binary and taking the longest chain of least-significant bits that are $0$.
> - We can find $b$ by dividing $y + 1$ by $2$ until it becomes odd.
>
> In either case we can directly get $n$ from $a$ as $n = \log_2(a)$ (or the number of bits in $a$), and $m$ from $b$ as $m = \frac{b−1}{2}$.

*The context for the binary usage is that previously, it was asserted that any output from this function has a binary form of: $m$ in binary, followed by a $0$, followed by $n$ $1$s, and this easy conversion method was offered as a preliminary reason to be confident in $\phi$'s bijectivity.*

My problem is with the bold part. It does not seem like a safe assumption to make that $a$ is odd and $b$ is even -- because this $\text{odd} \times \text{even}$ product can only describe the even numbers, never the odd numbers. For example, if $y + 1 = 1$ then $n = 0$ and so $2^n$ must be $1$ (which is odd). In fact, $2^n = 1$ has to be the case for *every* odd $y + 1$ we wish to express. In this case, *both* $a$ and $b$ must be odd, and so $\log_2(a) \notin \mathbb{N}$ in this instance (well, except for $a=1$).

Am I correct in concluding this proof's assumption is flawed?

Clarification: In this instance, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. It is considered a natural.

Comment: You should clarify whether or not you consider $0$ to be a natural number. I assume you do, since otherwise all your numbers would be odd, but you should state it explicitly.

Comment: To your question:  I agree that it is badly phrased.  I expect they meant to say that $y+1$ can be written as $2^k\times b$ where $b$ is odd (but $k$ might be $0$).  Note that this is decomposition you get if you follow their recipe.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable. I think, changing that, the rest of the proof is fine.